# Goldstein central force problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, orbital-motion, precession

I was reading Goldstein chapter 3 central force motion. I tried to do the exercise 21 on p. 130 of 3rd ed. but cant think of any way how to do it. any clue would be very helpful.

> Show that the motion of a particle in the potential field $$V(r)=-\frac{k}{r}+\frac{h}{r^2}$$ is the same as that of the motion under the Kepler potential alone when expressed in terms of a coordinate system rotating or precessing around the enter of force.

Thinking about the Euler Lagrange equation gives me
 $$
m\ddot{r}-\frac{l^2}{mr^3}=\frac{k}{r^2}-\frac{2h}{r^3}
$$
Now it seems natural to do 
$$
m\ddot{r}-\frac{l^2}{mr^3}+\frac{2h}{r^3}=\frac{k}{r^2}
$$
and setting $h=\frac{l^2}{2m}$ we get $m\ddot{r}=\frac{k}{r^2}$
i dont see how rotating coordinate coming? help please

Comment: The signs of the terms on the right hand side of your application of the Euler-Legrange equation are incorrect. Having corrected those signs you should aim to get an expression of the form $m\ddot{r}=\frac{(L+M)^2-M^2}{mr^3}+\frac{k}{r^2}$ where $M$ is an additional angular momentum term which is much smaller than $L$ and then make the appropriate approximation to get an expression which looks like a perturbed Keplerian equation of motion.

Comment: didnt understand sir.can you work out a little more